# How to store a NSManagedObjectID persistently?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, persistence

To avoid being an XY problem, here's some background:

My app allows users to create and save a lot of settings kinda like the Xcode's fonts and colors chooser:

[image]

This is because there are a lot of things that users can set. It would be easier to just tap on a saved setting instead of setting all those things again.

I used Core Data to store the settings the user saved. Each setting the user created is an instance of an `NSManagedObject` subclass. And now I need to store the selected setting persistently so that the user will have the same setting selected as before when the app reopens.

My first thought was to store the `NSManagedObject` subclass instance in `NSUserDefaults`. But according to the docs, I can't store it unless I convert it to `NSData`:

> A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.

Then I tried storing the `objectID` of the `NSManagedObject` subclass instance. I see that there is a `URIRepresentation()` method that returns an `NSURL`. So I thought this would work:

```
NSData(contentsOfURL: selectedOption!.objectID.URIRepresentation())
```

But the initializer failed somehow.

Now I realize that this is a stupid idea because even if I can convert it to `NSData`, I can't convert `NSData` back to `NSManagedObjectID`!

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568337/storing-nsmanagedobjectid-vs-nsmanagedobject), the OP seems to be able to store the object id:

> I store the selected theme objectID in NSUserDefaults so that when the app restarts, the selected theme will still be intact.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can simply store the string value of the URIRepresentation in NSUserDefaults. Later you can load that string then use `managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation` to get the NSObjectId and then `objectWithID` to get the NSManagedObject

Comment: @Paulw11 then how can I convert the string to the corresponding NSManagedObject?

Comment: As I said, by providing the URL to `managedObjectIDForURIRrepresentation` and the providing the object I'd that is returned to `objectWithID` On your managed object context

Comment: why not just store a flag in the data store to indicate the current selection, or a current settings entity with a relationship to current stuff - you don't need to use object IDs at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` has "convenience methods"

```
public func setURL(url: NSURL?, forKey defaultName: String)
public func URLForKey(defaultName: String) -> NSURL?
```

which allow to store and retrieve a `NSURL` like the one obtained
by `URIRepresentation()`. The conversion to and from `NSData`
is handled transparently. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class):

> When an NSURL is stored using `-[NSUserDefaults setURL:forKey:]`, some adjustments are made:
>
> 1. Any non-file URL is written by calling `+[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:]` using the NSURL instance as the root 
>      object.
> 2. ...
>
> When an NSURL is read using `-[NSUserDefaults URLForKey:]`, the following logic is used:
>
> 1. If the value for the key is an NSData, the NSData is used as the argument to `+[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:]`. If the NSData can be unarchived as an NSURL, the NSURL is returned otherwise nil is returned.
> 2. ...

So saving the managed object ID is simply done as

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setURL(object.objectID.URIRepresentation(),
                                             forKey: "selected")
```

and retrieving the object ID and the object for example like this:

```
if let url = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().URLForKey("selected"),
    let oid = context.persistentStoreCoordinator!.managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation(url),
    let object = try? context.existingObjectWithID(oid) {

    print(object)
    // ...
}
```

For alternative approaches of saving the selected settings, see [the above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953560/how-to-store-a-nsmanagedobjectid-persistently/38954198?noredirect=1#comment65262424_38953560).

Comment: So how can I convert the URL/NSData back to an NSManagedObject?

Comment: @Paulw11 already answered that question in the comments on the question

Comment: Thanks. I actually just came back from dinner. That's why I replied so late. :)